# Report Poll/Survey Custom POD - Adobe Connect

Tags: apache-flex, report, adobe, survey, adobe-connect

I have developed a custom POD using Flex, similar to the POLL integrated into adobe connect. The POD lets the owner of the meeting create a survey and then the connected users can complete it. I'd like to save the questions and results into the adobe connect `Reports -> By Question` area. I looked into every documentation available but I have not found anything useful. I can view/export the data added to adobe connect by the custom POLL. I would like to add the details on my own. Below is what I would like to achieve using the API:

[image: Report By Question]

[image]

[image]